# Civi Reporting - where's the preview tab?

Tags: civireport

I am building activity reports and the preview tab is missing from the top , likewise I am unable to access the report title tab.  is this something that can be added in , if so, how ? thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean you can't access the report title tab? In the navigation bar?

Answer (score 1):

If you have an older version of extended reports extension, or the advanced reports extension installed this can happen. Assuming you are on 4.7 make sure that if you have those extensions they are up-to-date